# Can i invite a user as with MCC with Adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api

I have been struggling with this, i know that the Google Adwords API has a bunch of service to create custom application with the AdWords, but with MCC i can invite a user that i would like to managed its account, so is there a Adwords call that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question from the oficial Adwords API Forum this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/adwords-api/browse_thread/thread/315b4265e54c794c/d8514d6c16a35299?lnk=gst&q=MCC+invitation+to+be+managed&pli=1) final response was:

> Hello,   That functionality is not
>   part of the AdWords API, no. Sorry to 
>   disappoint.  Cheers, 
>   -Jeff Posnick, AdWords API Team  On Sep 10, 2:05 pm, "j.e.frank"

That is too bad i needed that functionality ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Since v201302 u can invite other accounts via Google-AdWords-API.
Because i cant serve a better description please use this link to the API-Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/managing-accounts